# Anaconda 3 : Failed to create menus

Tags: python, anaconda

I am getting error **"Failed to create menus"** while installing Anaconda3 on windows 7 64-bit.

**Error details is shown below:**

Creating Anaconda3 menus...

> Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI29922\python36.dll'.
>   LoadLibrary: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: I'm just guessing here but that error might have something to do with user rights. Did you run the installer with admin permissions? If so: it's best to install Anaconda for a local user only (run it without admin permissions). See https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and none of the usual troubleshooting (admin rights, path, etc.) worked. Apparently it is related to the latest version distributions (2019.7, 2019.10 and possibly others).

Installing version 2019.3 from Anaconda Installer Archive (https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) worked for me. Hope this helps.